# Book with a tiny black hole on a planet

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember reading this book in a library around 2011. I suspect it was probably decently old at the time.

A central point involves a tiny black hole on the surface of an alien planet. I have a mental image of something about the size of a basketball, but don't remember if its size was actually explicitly stated. I also think it had some religious/ceremonial significance to the beings living there. Eventually the protagonist, a boy, approaches and enters the black hole, and witnesses time dilation of the outside world along the way. Inside the black hole is like a wormhole, with multiple different entrances/exits.

Comment: A basketball sized black hole has approximately the mass of Saturn. The planet would be within the black hole's Roche limit and break apart.

Comment: @Spencer Irrelevant to the question.